# Refresh time on via javascript (systemtime)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have an own PHP loginsystem. Users will be logged out after 5 min of inactivity. 
Now I want to show a timer in the right top corner to display the countdown.

At the moment I am using javascript.

Like this (Pseudo, haven't my code here at the moment):

```
var myTime = <?php echo time(); ?>; 
window.setInterval(myTime = myTime - 1; $("#timertext").text(myTime), 1000);
```

But I don't like this solution. I would like to use the current system time (php) and subtract the time, the user was active at last.

I found a solution to get the current system time via Ajax. But is this a good idea?

What do you think I could do to realize this counter? Is there a smart solution? Maybe a completely other way?

Comment: I guess getting time from AJAX or by direct inclusion of php time in your codes will yield the same thing . Ajax request and subtraction would be pointless, plus it will put load on your server unnecessary

Comment: Interested to know why you prefer using time from server for this?

Comment: Also note that ajax ping might false-trigger "activity" of your session

Comment: I'd start with considering what exactly an "activity" is. For example, when a user moves the mouse, does it count?

Comment: @CodingAnt Including the php-time in my javascript-code does not work. It is always the same time. I had this idea, too.

Comment: @georg Activity is loading a page. I reset the activity-time, while  I check, if the user is logged in. (On the top of each page)

Comment: can you share yor code @Korbi

Comment: @plbsam Because javascript.interval is not called, if the browser is minimized.

Comment: @CodingAnt I can do it this evening. But i did it like that.
"var myTime = <?php echo time(); ?>; "
time() always returns the time, when i was loading the html-page